# How to convert the following rails 2.3.x code to 3.2.13?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my ruby code for rails version 2.3.x in Rubymine. I want to convert the following code to rails 3.2.13 as this code is not supported by rails 3.2.13.

```
<h1>File Upload</h1> 
    <%= form_for({:action => :uploadFile}, :multipart => true) do %> 
    <p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label> : 
    <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p> 
    <%= submit_tag "Upload" %> 
    <% end %>
```

My controller code is :-

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :file => 'app\views\upload\uploadfile.html.erb'
  end
  def uploadFile
    post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

My view code is

```
<h1>File Upload</h1>
<%= form_for (:uploadFile, :multipart => true) do |f|%>
    <%= f.label :upload, 'Upload File' %>:
    <%= f.file_field :upload %></p>
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

Code in my route.rb file is

```
Uploadfile::Application.routes.draw do
get "upload/uploadfile"
```

Code in model is

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
  end
end
```

As mentioned in the question I want the code to run to rails 3.2.13

Comment: Please don't tag questions not specific to the IDE with `rubymine` tag.

Comment: follow http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 0):

Try This one :

```
<h1>File Upload</h1> 
  <%= form_for :file_upload, :html => {:multipart => true) do |f|%> 
  <%= f.label :upload, 'Upload File' %>:
  <%= f.file_field :upload %></p> 
  <%= f.submit "Upload" %> 
  <% end %>
```

In your controller :

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController

  def file_upload
    post = DataFile.save(params[:file_upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

Code in my route.rb file:

```
Uploadfile::Application.routes.draw do

resources :upload do
  get "file_upload"
end
```

I think it should work.

Comment: ..............error occured in line 2.....is there any way i can contact you by mail?? @Rails Guy

Comment: just paste your controller code in your question, and routing of this controller, I will make changes in that.

Comment: @ Rails Guy r u there??

Comment: @Pratik Sharma I updated my answer, if need any help, add comment.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvience but i would only be able to add comments tommorrow as this project is in my office desktop. I will tag you if i find any problem.

Comment: @ Rails Guy......if u are there the following error occured:-** Unknown action ** The action 'show' could not be found for UploadController